# Does Heroku have reverse proxy cache?

Tags: heroku, http-headers, reverse-proxy, cdn, http-caching

I've made a simple app that sets `Cache-Control: public, immutable, max-age=3600` in response headers. This app is purposely slow(sleep 2) to reproduce the issue.

My goal is to understand whether I can use Heroku for short term HTTP caching of API responses from my slow(in comparison with cache server) origin Heroku app.

From what I see there isn't any sort of HTTP caching by Heroku in front of my Heroku app.

**Actual behavior:**

Each request hits the origin/Heroku app:

```sh
$ curl https://cachecontroltest123.herokuapp.com/ --head
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: public, immutable, max-age=3600
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Server: WEBrick/1.4.2 (Ruby/2.6.6/2020-03-31)
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2020 09:28:51 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

**Expected behavior:**

After the first request, Heroku had to cache the response and for the upcoming hour serve it without hitting the (slow) origin.

I could find a few related questions on Stackoverflow, each of which saying that Heroku has a cluster of Varnish HTTP caching servers in front of each app but those answers are pretty old.
Have something changed since then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku does not do any HTTP caching.

This task is either to be done in your app (in the dyno, either by your framework or something like Varnish/Nginx),
or for more heavy load, by a CDN you put in front of the Heroku App ([Fastly](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fastly), [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)).

There's also the [Edge Heroku add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/edge) that simplifies AWS Cloudfront configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the Edge Addon, I didn't know about it.